# Routing under another child component in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been trying to route under a child component but it doesn't work out as i want. Below is the code;  I want to route under Notes Component. I created a route list called the GradedComponentList, yet still i am not able to route under the Notes Component.

//Dashboard route

```
export const AdminRoutes: Routes =[

  {
    path: 'dashboard',

    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'consumer'},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent},
      {path: 'task', component: RegisterFormComponent},
      {path: 'leads', component: DeleteFormList},
      {path: 'customer', component: NotesComponent,
        children: [...GradeComponentList]
      }
    ]
  }
```

//GradedComponentList

```
    import {GradedComponent} from '../Client/add_customer';


    export const GradedRouting : Routes = [
      {
        path: 'Graded',
        component: 'GradedComponent',
        children:[
          {path: 'add_grade', component: GradedComponent},
        ]
      }
    ];

//Dashboard 


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul id="active" class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
        <li class="active"><a routerLink="login"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class=""><a routerLink="customer"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>  Customer</a></li>
        <li class=""><a routerLink="leads"><i class="fa fa-database"></i>  Leads</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="task"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Teams</a></li>

<div id="page-wrapper">
  <div>
    <router-outlet ></router-outlet>


  </div>
```

Comment: What does "yet still i am not able to route" mean? Do you get an error message? How do the child routes `GradeComponentList` look like? How did you try to navigate to the route?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer,  I want to navigate from to GradedComponent from NotesComponent.  I am able to navigate to NotesComponent . I want to make GradedComponent a child of NotesComponent so i can navigate from NotesComponent to GradedComponent

Comment: What i have there basically

Comment: I see only route configurations but no router link or code that invokes navigation. So how did you try to navigate?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, when i navigate to contact page, i am not able to route to the GradedComponent which is under contact page (contact page is under dashboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
<a routerLink="/customer/Graded/add_grade">
```

or

```
<a routerLink="../Graded/add_grade">
```

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you mean with this comment.